# Jackie Robinson's Caught Stealing Totals

Tags: baseball

I'm doing some analysis on Jackie Robinson's career. I'm using both Retrosheet and Lahman's database in order get his performance per game and overall stats respectively.

The thing is that I see some discrepancies between these two data sources. Retrosheet game event files show that Robinson was CS 46 times between 1947 and 1950. However, Lahman database indicate that he was never caught stealing bases between these years.

Anyone knows which source has the correct information and why?

Retrosheet:

```
##      year.file SB CS  SB.P
## 1  all1947.csv 29 11 0.725
## 2  all1948.csv 22 14 0.611
## 3  all1949.csv 37 16 0.698
## 4  all1950.csv 12  5 0.706
## 5  all1951.csv 25  8 0.758
## 6  all1952.csv 24  7 0.774
## 7  all1953.csv 17  4 0.810
## 8  all1954.csv  7  3 0.700
## 9  all1955.csv 12  3 0.800
## 10 all1956.csv 12  6 0.667
```

Lahman:

```
## Source: local data frame [10 x 4]
## Groups: yearID
## 
##    yearID SB CS  SB.P
## 1    1947 29  0 1.000
## 2    1948 22  0 1.000
## 3    1949 37  0 1.000
## 4    1950 12  0 1.000
## 5    1951 25  8 0.758
## 6    1952 24  7 0.774
## 7    1953 17  4 0.810
## 8    1954  7  3 0.700
## 9    1955 12  3 0.800
## 10   1956 12  5 0.706
```

Comment: I am certain Lahman's is wrong.  After year 4 they would've just put him in the hall of fame and called it quits.  The current record is 50 consecutive SB's without getting caught by Vince Coleman.  In just the first 4 years, Lahman has Robinson at an even 100 in a row.   Doesn't mean Retrosheet is right, but if you had to choose one set...

Comment: I'm pretty sure CS wasn't counted for a long time, which is what you see in Lahman. It wasn't until people pulled the play by play (Retrosheet) that the CS numbers were available in the early years.

Comment: Folks, please post those as answers rather than comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure why some databases don't count the CS metric before 1950 as part of a player's career.  What is certain is that CS appear in the game log files. Kindly take a look at game log from [baseball reference](http://www.baseball-reference.com/boxes/BRO/BRO194705070.shtml).

Jackie got CS second base on the Bottom of the 1st.